# app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object error after deploying local shiny app

Tags: shinyapps

1. shiny app with two files (app.R and data.RDS) on local computer works
2. deploy shiny app to shinyapps.io
3. receives the following error during deployment

An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

Error in value[3L] : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object. Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution halted

4. tries to debug error and finds the following page http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html referenced by another question here on google group

I'm stuck as to how to debug this issue. Is this saying app.R needs to split into two files? If no, what are the steps I can do to fix/debug this error?

Comment: Link that You have posted is not working

Comment: Posting some of your code will help us look into this issue.